# Dynamic components in Angular 1.5.x

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, components

#### going beyond basics

To make it easier for people to understand what I am trying to do I made a simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h7Y7H0NDQkFXAz5ClaaA?p=preview) with a few components namely; `cList`, `cListItem`, `cAddItem`, `cEditItem`, `cPanel`.

The `Controller` passes an array of items (that it magically received from our data store) to `cList` component, which in turn renders each item.

`Add New Item` button supposed to initialise `cPanel` component when clicked and destroy? itself when the panel is closed or new item is created successfully.

Each item has an `edit` button which will initialise a panel with the item to edit. And just like `Add New Item` it should destroy itself when the panel is closed or item is updated successfully.

Simple CRUD, nothing fancy.

#### problems

- I don't quite understand how I should invoke the panels in the first place.
- If panels should be invoked from the `Controller`.
- If it is possible to initialise and destroy panels on the fly.
- If I should break `cAddItem` and `cEditItem` into separate modules instead (make it easier to handle display of panels?).
- If my implementation of `cPanel` component qualifies it as a reusable component.

Could you help me develop my example to a working prototype, please?

#### resources

Angular [Components](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/guide/component)
[Components](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) by Todd Motto
[$onInit and require](https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/) by Todd Motto

#### ps

I am using AngularJS 1.5.8

Comment: The term 'dynamic components' isn't correct because it may refer to a different thing. What you're trying to do is component interaction. Among the links you've posted the most relevant part is this one https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication .

Comment: @estus you would be correct in saying that is what I am trying to establish. However, I am not trying to achieve a parent-child relationship with my panels and that's where I get stuck. Do you have any thought?